# Laravel Sail connection refused with MySQL on localhost

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-sail

When I try to access via Laravel Sail in my local environment using Tinker, I get this error from MySQL:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select count(*) as
> aggregate from `users`...

Same thing (with an error) if I try to use MySQL Docker.

Comment: Please add some details like your Laravel version and env vars of DB

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.83.27. 
The ENV vars for DB are : 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=xxx

Comment: With Laravel Sail and a MySQL container the DB_HOST is NOT `127.0.0.1`. Check service name in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: for sail, the DB_HOST needs to be "mysql" -> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail